# Implementing long running tasks in background IOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have been working on an app in which user can record video using `AVFoundation` and send to the server, video has maximum size up to 15M, depending on the internet speed & type it can take from 1 to 5 minutes approximately to transfer video to the server. I am transferring the recorded video to the server in the background thread so that user can continue other stuff on the app while video is being uploaded to the server.

While reading the Apple Docs for [implementing long running tasks in backround](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), I see that only few kinds of apps are allowed to execute in the background.
e.g.

> audio—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)

Does it qualify my app also for running the tasks in the background? or I need to transfer the video on the main thread?

Comment: ru going to upload the record video in background ?

Comment: yes this is what i am doing, reason I mentioned that I want the user to continue doing other stuff on the form while video is being recorded

Comment: While uploading, ur app will in foreground (perform some other task) or it will enter into the background completely?

Comment: only the uploading process goes in the background, all other stuff remains on the main thread and user can continue adding details within app

Comment: background running doesn't care on which thread your uploading is running. If you are talking about keeping uploading when after user tap home button, then background task is what you want. If you are talking about uploading while running in foreground, then you mean on a background thread. Background thread and background running are two concepts.

Comment: @Dwayne I have this situation in which user can continue using app, or can press the home button, and upload process continues in the background, but my concern is also if user press the power button, WIFI could be disconnected in that situation and uploading process might be disturbed

Comment: @nsgulliver if you want to upload only in wifi environment, then may be UIRequirePersistentWifi key in info.plist may help. Also you can use reachability to define if you are using wifi or 3G.

Comment: I don't require only WIFI, i need all kind of internet availability, and situation may arise when internet connection goes down and for that I am using the reachability already to notify the user, but by doing background thread execution will resume the tasks once internet is available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSOperationQueue` is the recommended way to perform multi-threaded tasks to avoid blocking the main thread. Background thread is used for tasks that you want to perform while your application is inactive, like GPS indications or Audio streaming.

If your application is running in foreground, you don't need background thread at all.

For simple tasks, you can add a operation to a queue using a block:

```
NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Perform long-running tasks without blocking main thread
}];
```

More info about [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [how to use it](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/).

The upload process will continue while in background, but your application will be eligible to be suspended, and thus the upload may cancel. To avoid it, you can add the following code to application delegate to tell the OS when the App is ready to be suspended:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

      // Wait until the pending operations finish
      [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

      [application endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: does that mean if user clicks the power button and `NSOperationQueue` will continue its tasks?

Comment: See updated answer to avoid the App being suspended while inactive.

Comment: Add `*` sign to NSOperationQueue `*`operationQueue

Comment: What is bgTask in this context ??

Comment: @jesses.co.tt a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`

Comment: @redent84 yeah, figured that out on another post, but thx. wish the default example code from Apple would declare it in scope...

Answer (score 5):

From your response to Dwayne, you do not need to be able to download in background mode.  Rather what you need is to do your download in another thread (background thread) beside main thread.  Something like this for GCD:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//        Do you download here...
    });
```

Comment: it is uploading of data to the server and, my concern is that if internet goes down and become available after sometime, will it resume my tasks? will have to add the tasks in NSOperationQueue as I understand and if they are pending then can resume?

Comment: Whether or not your uploading task will be able to resume after losing connection to server will depend on the library you are using would have this feature.  Running a task as a background task or in a background thread would not help if that library doesnot support that feature.

Comment: and what are those libraries which have ability to resume and which don't?

Answer (score 4):

Your requirement qualifies to run in background. You do not need to register any background modes supported in the info plist. All you need to do is, when the app is about to go into background, request for additional time using background task handler and perform your task in that block. Make sure you stop your handler before 10 mins so as to not get force terminated by the OS.

You may use the below code from Apple.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});}
```

Comment: from Apple Docs it is not clear, that is why I have asked, I am already implementing my uploading process in the background thread and I am using multitasking already, my question is that will it make my app to be rejected if it is running already in the background thread? secondly my app can be in active or inactive state, does not matter because it is performing the tasks in the background thread.

Comment: @nsgulliver No. Apple will not reject because you upload using the background handler. All you need to do is make sure you are stopping the handler before 10 minutes of time failing which the app may be force terminated by the OS. I have done so in a few applications and I did not have any problem with Apple.