# Handle long running tasks and Parse.com API

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am kind of new to iOS so I am not sure how to handle my problem.

The issue I am concerned about is when a user in my app says they want to remove their account and I delete all there data from my backend held in `Parse`. There are several tables I have to go through to delete the users data and depending on the amount of data it can take some time. During this time the user could always put the app in the background because they didnt want to wait or something.

here is an example of what I do

```
var commentKeys:Comment.CommentKeys = Comment.CommentKeys()
        var qComment = Comment.query()
        qComment.whereKey("id", equalTo: account.getId())
        qComment.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(results: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                if((results as NSArray).count > 0){
                    for item in (results as NSArray){
                        (item as Comment).deleteInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

that is just one table and there are `6` more I have to clear.

If these dont all clear it could cause data to be orphaned. How can I prevent this, is there a way to allow the execution to complete even if the app has been backgrounded?

I [Implementing long running tasks in background IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268702/implementing-long-running-tasks-in-background-ios) but that is using `NSOperationQueue` and I am not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

1.) Check out Parse Cloud Code. You'll be able to create a deleteThisUser(objectId) function, which will allow you to delete the user and all related data on the server.

2.) You may want to organize your tables more efficiently or query them more efficiently. With Parse SDK you are able to query multiple objects and destroy() multiple objects within the same request.

You can store related objects as pointers within an object.
For example you could store the post in which the comments are related to as a pointer within the comment object. If the post was written by the user that can also be deleted. This is a bad example, but this should show the concept so you can apply it elsewhere.

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToBeDeleted = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
 // Retrieve the most recent ones
 [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
 [query whereKey:@"id", equalTo: account.getId()];

 // Include the post data with each comment
 [query includeKey:@"post"];

 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *comment in comments) {

        // add comment to be deleted
        [objectsToBeDeleted addObject:comment];

        //get the post from the pointer contained in the comment object
        PFObject *post = comment[@"post"];

        //Check to see if the post was written by the current user
        if(post[@"authorId"] ==  account.getId()){
             //add the post to be deleted also
             [objectsToBeDelted addObject:post];
        }

    }
    // Accepts an NSArray containing one or more PFObject instances
    [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:objectsToBeDeleted];
}];
```

I imagine the deleteAllInBackground: method will accept an NSMutableArray, but if not you can use this code:

```
NSArray *arrayToDelete = [objectsToBeDeleted copy];
// Accepts an NSArray containing one or more PFObject instances
[PFObject deleteAllInBackground:arrayToDelete];
```

Good luck

Comment: Cloud Code is probably what I am going to do but can you elaborate on number 2 a little more, how can I delete multiple objects like you said?